# How to set the MockBackend status code?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

For an HTTP test I've got these providers ..

```
  providers: [
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (pBackend: MockBackend, pOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(pBackend, pOptions);
      },
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    }
  ]
```

I can mock a success response ..

```
let backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
backend.connections.subscribe(
  (connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(
      new ResponseOptions({
          body: {mydata:'somedata'}
        }
      )));
  });
```

and an error response ..

```
let backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
backend.connections.subscribe(
  (connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockError(new Error('error'));
  });
```

but please, how do i mock a non 200 response. E.G. how do I respond with HTTP status code 418 for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a status property to the `ResponseOptions`

```
new ResponseOptions({
  body: {mydata:'somedata'},
  status: 418
})
```

See [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/ResponseOptions-class.html) for other properties

Comment: Just to note - that wouldn't trigger the `catch` function, or the second function on `.subscribe`, if that's what he's trying to test in his unit test